# Does HTTP protocol facilitate for specification of URI(s) associated with an authentication realm?

Tags: http, authentication, http-headers, authorization

As a preface I'd like to claim I have *some* understanding of how the HTTP-supported authentication is supposed to work according to [RFC 7235](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235).

I am specifically interested to know how a client is supposed to know, after authenticating, which URIs on the server it is expected to provide same authorization (through the `Authorization` header) bearer for? Furthermore, is there any provision in HTTP to assist client in determining which `Authorization` headers that it (the client) may have available (through whatever means it acquires them -- "login" form/dialog etc), correspond to which realm(s)?

A realm doesn't seem to be specified in the form of an URI or even a regular expression of an URI, it's a value the interpretation of which appears to be left to the HTTP client application. Of note, [a "Protection Space (Realm)" is defined](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-2.2), quoting:

> A protection space is defined by the canonical root URI (the scheme and authority components of the effective request URI (see Section 5.5 of RFC7230) of the server being accessed, in combination with the realm value if present.

The above is all well and good, but it doesn't facilitate client mapping realms to URIs that may require authorization.

Say my Web server returns a response with status code 401 and the `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="The hangout"` header line, for a request with a given URI, let's say `/foobar`. That makes it obvious that subsequent requests to the particular URI must include `Authorization` header line corresponding to solved challenge (as the client authenticates the user). No problem there. But what about e.g. requests with URI(s) that have the same *pathname* - those starting with `/foobar/` -- is there an implication here that the same `Authorization` value is expected for these as well? What about entirely unrelated URI pathnames [on the same server]?

It would seem beneficial for the kind of authorization negotiation HTTP already does, to somehow relate or facilitate said relation of realms to URIs. But maybe I am missing something very obvious. Does HTTP do something along of what I am describing? Does it facilitate it in any way, at least, beyond leaving it entirely to the application? How would one realistically let the client determine which authorization bearer to send for which requests? Must it always get a 401 and a challenge response first, before knowing for sure requests to the particular URI and only said URI, must include related authorization bearer?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is a stateless protocol that deals with a request-response pair. The protocol does not deal with any information that would describe the concept of a "page", "site", "application", etc. Even though it deals with hypermedia, the protocol itself doesn't go beyond the concrete request. This means that you won't get any information from the protocol itself about any other paths under the same domain that are in the same authentication realm. This is left to the documentation of APIs or websites.

Comment: Hi Michal, didn't want to leave you hanging without response. In all honesty, I consider most of your answer to be information I already know. The last two sentences, furthermore, appear unsubstantiated in the sense that they don't, according to my reasoning, automatically follow from the rest of your answer. In short, I don't see how the properties of HTTP you described, necessarily forbid or preclude potential association between, say, realms and sets of URIs. Your answer is useful as it facilitates discussion, but there's just not enough meat on the bones here for me to award the bounty.

Comment: It's not that those properties forbid that. What I meant was that the specification of the protocol doesn't define anything that would facilitate it. The functionality that you describe is left solely to the creator of the API, e.g. they can use URIs as the realm value and let the integrators know that the same auth has to be used across the URI-defined realm. There are other specs that do something like that. E.g. in OpenAPI you can define auth type/scopes/etc for every endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your research is centered on one type of authentication process that we call **basic auth**, know they are some other ways to authenticate a user and that they might suits your needs better as basic auth is kinda old as you can see on that RFC you linked.

To my understanding, the principle behind basic auth is to have a simple process based on challenges. When your client asks for a resource and that resource is protected by authentication, the server responds with a challenge : 401 Unauthorized with a header `WWW-authenticate: Basic realm="some realm"`. The client then know the resource is restricted and depending on the realm, knows if it can have access (or asks the user for credentials for that realm), and try to access with a basic auth header : `Authorization: Basic viFWGrwehryfviehtNRBRGWrwGERThRGE`. You then repeat that process every time you need a resource.

HTTP and basic auth don't implement any sort of deeper and more complex system for authentication like you're searching for. It's one of the simplest system as its name implies and has not a lot more to offer. I'd even add that it's one of the riskier way to authenticate a system (even using SSL cert and cert pinning) as the client must send credentials for every single authenticated resource request.

In case you want to search other ways to authenticate requests, here are some :
OAuth (2.0) (most secured and complex)
Bearer (JWT or session tokens)
API keys

Comment: Hi Damien. What made you believe I was specifically asking about `Basic` authentication? I didn't mention it at all? I even have `Bearer` mentioned instead in the question, which could be interpreted as me asking in context of [OAuth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750), specifically. Which would also be a stretch, if I read my question myself. The scope was always general and not about a specific authentication scheme. And `realm` key-value pair _is_ applicable no matter the former, it doesn't apply to the "basic" scheme specifically, which is part of why I asked my question.

Comment: Sorry, bad interpretation of my part about what I read. I never encountered a system where multiple realms were handle by the client, and where the client used the WWW-authenticate header, I assumed it was basic auth stuff. That might be bad practice but in my previous experiences, the client was developed being aware of the auth necessary for authenticated routes, and that was based on back-front interface documentation, usually swagger files. I guess in the end none of what I said helps you more than what Michal Trojanowski said (and I agree with their response), hope you find your answer